# How to run multiple spark streaming batch jobs at the same time?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have been using spark streaming to process data in Spark 2.1.0.

9 receivers receive data in 10 second intervals by streaming.
The average processed time is about 10 seconds since my submitted the streaming application. However, the queued batches delayed more than one day.

Is the queue in the driver? Or is it in each receiver executer?

And in Active Batch processing, only one real data processing batch is processed except 9 receivers. So there are always only 10 batches running.

I am inquiring how to increase the number of active batches processing data.

And there is only one Streaming Batch job at a time. I set spark.scheduler.mode to FAIR in SparkConf and set the schedule pool to fair, but the batch job only runs one at a time.

In the spark job scheduling guide, the fair pool is supposed to operate as a FIFO in the same pool. Is this right?

How to run multiple spark streaming batch jobs at the same time?

- spark streaming run spark-yarn client mode
- 8 node cluster, 1 node : 32core, 128G
- executor_memory: 6g
- executor_cores: 4
- driver-memory: 4g
- sparkConf.set("spark.scheduler.mode", "FAIR")
- ssc.sparkContext.setLocalProperty("spark.scheduler.pool",
  "production")
- production is FAIR pool
- sparkConf.set("spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled", false)